# WebView content inside of bottom sheet of the ModalBottomSheetLayout is not scrollable

Tags: android, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I am trying to implement WebView in a ModalBottomSheetLayout. Issue is that WebView content is not scrolling inside bottom sheet. It works fine in normal compose view. Couldn't find anything workable. Is there a way to make it working?

Comment: Could you add more details into how you have implemented this so we could help?

Comment: Using accompanist web view library fixed this issue for me.

Comment: @Bpn could you please provide more details how have you solved the issue? I'm experiencing the same, and I have problem to resolve it.

Comment: I have this problem with the accompanist WebView

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you? Let me know if this works for you.

```
    Column(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            loadUrl(url)
        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(url)
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: Yup! Had the same exact issue... This was it!